# How to Add an item to All Tree Array's Objects in Js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, tree, treeview

I would like to id all the objects inside my tree array sequentially. To do this, I need to iterate all the array objects and objects' children, grandchildren etc.. and insert **rowId** to each.

What I have;

```
rows={[
  {
    car: 'Audi A4',
    city: 'Las Vegas',
    items: null,
    name: 'Sandra',
    sex: 'Female'
  },
  {
    car: 'Chevrolet Cruze',
    city: 'Tokyo',
    items: [
      {
        car: 'BMW 750',
        city: 'London',
        items: [
          {
            car: 'Toyota Corolla',
            city: 'Chicago',
            name: 'David',
            sex: 'Male'
          },
        ],
        name: 'Robert',
        sex: 'Male'
      }
    ],
    name: 'Sharon',
    sex: 'Female'
  }
]}
```

What I expect;

```
rows={[
  {
    car: 'Audi A4',
    city: 'Las Vegas',
    items: null,
    name: 'Sandra',
    sex: 'Female',
    rowId: 1
  },
  {
    car: 'Chevrolet Cruze',
    city: 'Tokyo',
    items: [
      {
        car: 'BMW 750',
        city: 'London',
        items: [
          {
            car: 'Toyota Corolla',
            city: 'Chicago',
            name: 'David',
            sex: 'Male',
            rowId: 2
          },
        ],
        name: 'Robert',
        sex: 'Male',
        rowId: 3
      }
    ],
    name: 'Sharon',
    sex: 'Female',
    rowId: 4
  }
]}
```

I could do this iteration like this when there is no inner objects;

```
rows.map((row, index) => ({ ...row, rowId: index }));
```

Also tried some recursive methods but none of them worked actually neither found something useful on the web.

Looking for a genius developer who can guide me through this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have to have the numbering go from the inner-most to the outer or can it be the opposite or any direction?

Comment: I need to number from inner most to the outer like in the sample object. The customized datagrid we use requres that unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) algorithm and add `id` to each object.

```js
const addId = (data, id) => {
        const iter = array => array.forEach(o => {
            if (o.items) iter(o.items); // search first
            o.id = id++;                // add later
        });
        iter(data);
    };
    
var rows = [{ car: 'Audi A4', city: 'Las Vegas', items: null, name: 'Sandra', sex: 'Female' }, { car: 'Chevrolet Cruze', city: 'Tokyo', items: [{ car: 'BMW 750', city: 'London', items: [{ car: 'Toyota Corolla', city: 'Chicago', name: 'David', sex: 'Male' },], name: 'Robert', sex: 'Male' }], name: 'Sharon', sex: 'Female' }];

addId(rows, 1);
   
console.log(rows);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```